# Best way to specify variable in code snippet

Tags: naming-conventions

I've seen countless way to give a specific thing in code snippet.

For example : `C:\Users\[YourUserName]\Documents` or `git clone <someUrl>`.

Is there a official convention, or is it just a "put something that isn't confusing" thing ?

Comment: There is no single convention that I know of. For paths you could have a look at the Windows documentation and for commands you can see what is used in the manual pages.